# ValueError: An operation has None for gradient. while implementing custom keras loss between different layers

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function, consensus

I'm trying to implement this a custom loss function in keras.

My objective functions are

1. Consensus Agreement

[image: consensus agreement]

2. cross entropy

[image: cross entropy]

where fi is output of different layers, ui is weights.

```
#f123 = concatenate([f1, f2, f3])
#f = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(f123)


def consensus(f1,f2,f3, f):

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    CP = K.square(f1-f2) + K.square(f2-f3) + K.square(f3-f1)
    CE = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy() 
    L = CE(y_true, f)
    return CP + L
return loss
```

where f is

I'm getting following error log

[image: error log]

raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

Comment: Can you have look into this link - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511